# How to remove tabcolsep in the first column of all tabulars in one place?

Tags: tables, indentation

I want to vertically align the first column of all my tables the text. I can change the \tabcolsep using `@{}` but I how can I declare this in a single place as a default value?

Edit: I added an MWE below.

2nd Edit: I modified the question according to your comments. Thank you for clarifying that this is indeed no indent but the tabcolsep.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
This is some normal text. This is some normal text. This is some normal text. This is some normal text.\\
\begin{tabular}{@{}ll@{}}
    This is aligned with the text &abc\\
\end{tabular}
\newline
\begin{tabular}{ll}
    This is not aligned with the text   &abc\\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Untested: `\AtBeginEnvironment{tabular}{\parindent=0pt}` -- requires `etoolbox`

Comment: @ChristianHupfer: Probably \AtBeginEnvironment{table}. I don't see parindent inside of tabulars.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: Of course -- I meant `table`. Thanks for correction.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Unfortunately this does not seem to work, I will add an MWE.

Comment: @KonradHöffner: ... which is always the best idea ;-)

Comment: note that tabular do not have any indentation code that can be disabled, they are just positioned like a letter. If you put them at the start of a paragraph then they may be indented depending on the paragraph settings, although possibly using `\centering` is more common in which case there is usually no indentation.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer parindent in normally zero in table already.

Comment: I think the OP does not mean indentation but the col sep left of the first and right of the last column.

Comment: @clemens: If this is true he should not distract users here with `\parindent` then

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Thanks for clarifying that the `\parindent` is not the issue here. I clarified my question.

Comment: @KonradHöffner You could try this `\AtBeginEnvironment{tabular}{\noindent\hspace*{-\tabcolsep}}`, but not suggested for `\begin{tabular}{@{}ll@{}}`!

Answer (score 1):

It’s easy peasy with `tblr` environment of my new LaTeX3 package [`tabularray`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tabularray), since you can use `\SetTblrInner` command to set the default styles of `tblr` environments.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularray}

\SetTblrInner{
  column{1} = {leftsep=0pt}
}

\begin{document}

This is some normal text. This is some normal text.
This is some normal text. This is some normal text.

\bigskip

\begin{tblr}{colspec={ll},hlines}
  This is aligned with the text & abc\\
\end{tblr}

\bigskip

\begin{tblr}{colspec={ll},hlines}
  This is also aligned with the text & abc\\
\end{tblr}

\end{document}
```

[image]